# AEM issue on publish - Complete page loads only on login

Tags: aem

I am using AEM 6.3 on a windows machine. When I access the page on localhost:4503 it loads only partially as shown in the screenshot. But when I go to crx and login using admin/admin the page loads perfectly. Without doing the login process, neither the clientlibs are loaded nor does the header and footer components which are getting rendered through the editable template. No error on browser console either.

If it makes any difference, all the clientlibs are placed in the etc/clientlibs folder. I have also provided the screenshot of the pages before and after login.

before login:

[image]

after login:

[image]

Please let me know if there is anything else I need to provide.

Thanks

Comment: check the network tab for the response code for clientlibs.

Answer (score 2):

Check permissions for the stuff that isn't loading.  If the clientlibs, the header, and the footer are in locations that don't allow anonymous access, then browser requests for these would get 404s.  Resources under /etc don't have anonymous access by default in recent AEM versions.

See https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/administering/using/security.html for details on managing permissions and check what permissions the "everyone" group has for the resources that aren't loading.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for their inputs which made me check the editable template settings and it was missing the rep:policy nodes. I copied the rep:policy nodes under policy, templates and template-types nodes and it started working.

Answer (score 1):

you need to give read access to your clientlibs (mostly under etc/clientlibs) for anonymous user if you want to load page properly with all css and js with out authentication in publisher.

Answer (score 0):

The publisher has a more restricted set of permissions then the author instance has. What's most likely occurring is that the content that's being rendered is doing something that can only be done with a specific set of permissions.

Examples of this could be:

1. Accessing content that is not under the /content directory
2. Attempting to modify content during rendering

Occasionally errors will show up in the source of the page and not the log files, you can usually get a good idea of where the error is occurring by seeing where the page stops rendering. Additionally increasing the level of logging during the request will help as well